# How to Efficiently Process Time-Series Data in Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, time-series

I have data sets representing travel times past given nodes. The data is in one CSV file per node in this format:
`node name, datetime, irrelevant field, mac address`

I'm reading them into one DataFrame in Pandas:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, names=CSV_COLUMNS, parse_dates=[1]) for f in files]
return pd.concat(dfs)
```

What I want to do is find the time difference between a MAC address' appearance at one node and the next. Right now I'm looping over the resulting DataFrame, which isn't efficient and isn't working: every way I've tried to sort the data causes a problem.

- I can't sort it by MAC and date and time because I need to preserve the direction of travel (sorting by date and time results in all direction looking like it's in the positive direction).
- Sorting by MAC alone keeps the nodes in order (because they are pushed into the file in node order)

While I may be able to figure out the sorting problem, the larger issue is I'm new to Pandas and I bet there's a right way to do this in Pandas. What I want at the end of processing is a data set that shows travel time (`timediff.total_seconds()` or similar) for every pair of nodes that a MAC *traveled directly between*. That last bit is important: for a layout where the nodes are A, B and C, most travel will be A-B or B-C (or the reverse), but it is possible some MACs won't register at B and will go A to C. It's also possible some of the appearances will be orphans where a MAC appears at a node but never shows up at another node.

Comment: i'm confused: why can you not sort by date and time? things always travel forward in time (except like photons), so why wouldn't the date and time the same as the direction of travel?

Comment: Might be a bad assumption on my part: I need to know whether the person was going from A to B or B to A. I suppose that doesn't mean I can't sort it by date time, but I'd need to know start node and end node.

Comment: and how would you determine that using anything other than time? unless the individual nodes times aren't synced up AND you have no idea how much they were off, if i see something arriving at A at 9:30 and B at 9:40, i'm going to go ahead and assume that that thing just went from A to B

Comment: The thing you're totally missing is that I am an idiot who can't see his nose in front of his face some days. Because Pandas is new to me I'm so caught up with trying to see into the opaque process that I didn't think through just using the node names to figure out which way they went.

Comment: sorry! but glad you figured it out. pandas is def confusing at first, but it's really powerful. at that point, once it's sorted, you could just use something like `df.arrival_time - df.arrival_time.shift(1)`

Comment: See comments on the answer below: at least in his approach, that's 50x slower than looping the rows by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the dataframe is sorted by datetime for each `mac address`, probably you can do:

```
grb = df.groupby('mac address')
df['origin'] = grb['node name'].transform(pd.Series.shift, 1)
df['departure time'] = grb['datetime'].transform(pd.Series.shift, 1)
```

and the travel time would be:

```
df['travel time'] = df['departure time'] - df['datetime']
```

and if node names are string, the path would be:

```
df['path'] = df['origin'] + '-' + df['node name']
```

*edit*: this may be faster assuming travel times cannot be negative:

```
df.sort(['mac address', 'datetime'], inplace=True)

df['origin'] = df['node name'].shift(1)
df['departure time'] = df['datetime'].shift(1)

# correct for the places where the mac addresses change
idx = df['mac address'] != df['mac address'].shift(1)
df.loc[idx, 'origin'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx, 'departure time'] = np.nan
```

Comment: How would I find the two node names in that case?

Comment: Not sure it matters: this approach appears to be at least one order of magnitude slower than simply looping over the rows. If it ever finishes, I'll update how many orders of magnitude.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work: looping over the rows takes 15 seconds whereas this takes 753. Thanks for giving me some new ideas though.

Comment: @Tom how about the alternative method?

Comment: @Tom, i would suggest playing around with `for name, group in grb:` and seeing what you can figure out from there. with the vectorization of these functions, it should be way faster.

Comment: @behzad.nouri the alternative method is right in line with the row iteration so it should be a good replacement. Thanks.