# Pandas: Filtering and Shifting on a DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

This is a follow-on to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534225/how-to-efficiently-process-time-series-data-in-pandas). I've managed to accomplish what I want to do, but I've done so without using an index column. For performance reasons and additional functionality, I'd like to turn my datetime column into an index, but I get stuck when trying to do that. Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, names=CSV_COLUMNS, parse_dates={'timestamp': [1, 2]}, date_parser=parse) for f in files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df = df[(df['timestamp'] >= start)]
df['day'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.isoweekday())
df = df[df['day'].isin(self.days)]
df.sort(columns=['mac', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
df['departure time'] = df['timestamp'].shift(1)
# mask out items outside our hour bounds
df['hour'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['departure hour'] = df['hour'].shift(1)
# get rid of items outside our time range or with NaN values in either hour column
df = df[(df['departure hour'] >= self.time_range[0].hour) & (df['hour'] <= self.time_range[1].hour)]
```

I can't figure out how to do a couple of the items when I make the `timestamp` columns into an index:

- when I try to perform the shift for `departure hour` I get "cannot shift with no offset".
- I'm also not sure how to get an ISO Weekday out of the index column but I think I can fake that by using `.weekday` and adjusting by 1.

What I'd really like is to have the convenience of the `timestamp` column I have now combined with the performance of a DateTimeIndex (and the ability to do frequency analysis). Also, if I'm doing something completely backwards, that would be good to know as well.

EDIT: here's a (wrapped) view of the dataframe after running the code above:

```
                   timestamp    node                mac  day  origin  \
0 2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737  node32  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node31   
0 2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211  node33  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node32   
0 2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526  node34  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node33   
0 2013-09-13 16:02:40.336842  node35  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node34   
0 2013-09-13 16:03:50.347368  node36  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node35   

              departure time  hour  departure hour      node_key  time_elapsed  
0        2013-09-13 15:59:59    16              15  node31node32     14.494737  
0 2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737    16              16  node32node33     41.589474  
0 2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211    16              16  node33node34     42.726315  
0 2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526    16              16  node34node35     62.526316  
0 2013-09-13 16:02:40.336842    16              16  node35node36     70.010526
```

Comment: very helpful to show an actual frame that matches what you are reading from the file. that can be constructed simply by copy/pasting (with random data if you can't show yours).

Answer (score 1):

FYI posting wrapped data is really hard to parse, better to just paste and let the scroll bar work. Then I can just copy/past directly.

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]: 
                   timestamp    node                mac  day  origin             departure time  hour  depart_hour      node_key  time_elapsed
0 2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737  node32  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node31        2013-09-13 15:59:59    16           15  node31node32     14.494737
1 2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211  node33  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node32 2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737    16           16  node32node33     41.589474
2 2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526  node34  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node33 2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211    16           16  node33node34     42.726315
3 2013-09-13 16:02:40.336842  node35  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node34 2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526    16           16  node34node35     62.526316
4 2013-09-13 16:03:50.347368  node36  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node35 2013-09-13 16:02:40.336842    16           16  node35node36     70.010526

[5 rows x 10 columns]

In [57]: df.dtypes
Out[57]: 
timestamp         datetime64[ns]
node                      object
mac                       object
day                        int64
origin                    object
departure time    datetime64[ns]
hour                       int64
depart_hour                int64
node_key                  object
time_elapsed             float64
dtype: object
```

I think that you have the correct dtypes for the date columns as you it looks like you are parsing them on read-in.

The difference between what I have and what you are showing is the index. When you concat, 
do `concat(list_of_frames,ignore_index=True)` in this case because I'll bet that the read in dfs's have an index starting with 0, so you want a unique consecutive index.

you can do various operations in a vectorized way by wrapping the series in an index then performing index operations.

```
In [58]: pd.Index(df['timestamp']).weekday
Out[58]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])

In [59]: pd.Index(df['timestamp']).hour
Out[59]: array([16, 16, 16, 16, 16])
```

Set the index and shift

```
In [65]: df2 = df.set_index('timestamp')

In [69]: df2.shift(1)
Out[69]: 
                              node                mac  day  origin             departure time  hour  depart_hour      node_key  time_elapsed
timestamp                                                                                                                                   
2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737     NaN                NaN  NaN     NaN                        NaT   NaN          NaN           NaN           NaN
2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211  node32  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node31        2013-09-13 15:59:59    16           15  node31node32     14.494737
2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526  node33  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node32 2013-09-13 16:00:13.494737    16           16  node32node33     41.589474
2013-09-13 16:02:40.336842  node34  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node33 2013-09-13 16:00:55.084211    16           16  node33node34     42.726315
2013-09-13 16:03:50.347368  node35  00:05:4F:90:0D:C5    5  node34 2013-09-13 16:01:37.810526    16           16  node34node35     62.526316

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

I am not entirely clear what your questions are, so maybe edit your post.

Comment: >FYI posting wrapped data is really hard to parse, better to just paste and let the scroll bar work. 

It's how it came out on the console, wrapped at 80 characters regardless of my console width-- is there something I can use to get it to dump out as one line per row?

Comment: "I'll bet that the read in dfs's have an index starting with 0, so you want a unique consecutive index." - Can you explain what that means/ the implications are? Also, the set index and shift part confuses me a bit: I actually want the `departure time` column to be the previous row's index/ timestamp, so I'm doing a `.shift(1)` to get that but it blows up when I set timestamp as an index as part of the parse. I'll check to see if your approach fixes that. Thanks.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/faq.html; I usually set expand_repr to False (or just set a really large width)